# click file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen día, estoy trabajando con el plugin jQuery-File-Upload y tengo un problema con el navegador de chrome, tengo un botton que está en dos menús diferentes cuando estoy en el menú principal doy click y y abre la ventana de diálogo para subir una imagen, pero cuando Estoy en el otro menú tiene que volver al menú principal y abrir la ventana de diálogo pero no lo hace, pero esto sólo me pasa en el navegador de chrome.

Comment: The language of this site is Spanish, please change the question to spanish or use the english version of stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Agrega código, sino es bastante difícil ayudarte. La idea es que entregues un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)